# Replace preg_replace to preg_replace_callback function in PHP 5.5

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

Here are the original two functions which runs okay in PHP 5.2:

```
function highlight($text, $words, $prepend) {
    $text = str_replace('\"', '"', $text);
    foreach($words AS $key => $replaceword) {
        $text = str_replace($replaceword, '<highlight>'.$replaceword.'</highlight>', $text);
    }
    return "$prepend$text";
}

function search_highlight($message, $words, $color = '#ff0000') {
    if(!empty($words)) {
        $highlightarray = explode(' ', $words);
        $sppos = strrpos($message, chr(0).chr(0).chr(0));
        if($sppos !== FALSE) {
            $specialextra = substr($message, $sppos + 3);
            $message = substr($message, 0, $sppos);
        }
        $message = preg_replace(array("/(^|>)([^<]+)(?=<|$)/sUe", "/<highlight>(.*)<\/highlight>/siU"), array("highlight('\\2', \$highlightarray, '\\1')", "<strong><font color=\"$color\">\\1</font></strong>"), $message);
        if($sppos !== FALSE) {
            $message = $message.chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).$specialextra;
        }
    }
    return $message;
}
```

To test the function:

```
search_highlight("here is the test content","test");
```

The result, `test` will be highlight show.

But in PHP 5.5, the [`e` modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (`PREG_REPLACE_EVAL`) for `preg_replace` is deprecated — how can I replace the `preg_replace` function to `preg_replace_callback`?

The line:

```
$message = preg_replace(array("/(^|>)([^<]+)(?=<|$)/sUe", "/<highlight>(.*)<\/highlight>/siU"), array("highlight('\\2', \$highlightarray, '\\1')", "<strong><font color=\"$color\">\\1</font></strong>"), $message);
```

to

```
$message = preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern, 
    $callback,
    $message
);
```

I'm confused how to do it.

Comment: Wha, `preg_replace` deprecated? The `e` modifier is but the function is certainly not

Comment: @Phil: I think he means the `e` modifier. Edited the question to clarify.

Comment: only the e modifier is deprecated not preg_replace !!

Comment: yes!thx @AmalMurali,I means the modifier